# Get photos and photo albums from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a client who wants  albums, pictures from her Facebook account to appear on her website automatically, so she does not have to manage them in two places.

I spent a couple of hours researching and did not find anything that explains exactly this scenario. I read a bunch about authentication and access tokens in facebook developers documentation, but still don't have a clear picture for my scenario.

The thing I know for sure is that end users of my client's web site do not have to have a facebook account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you'll need to set up an application on facebook, and specify you'll be using it on a website. You can do that at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/

since you mention c# (which is vary hard to work with), here's the best way to do it in JS:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script language="javascript">
var facebookappid = '##FACEBOOK_APP_ID##';
//this is the site owners facebook id. note she must make all her galleries and pictures public
var userid = '8979567465474';

//load the facebook SDK
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: facebookappid, status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());

//get albums
var albums;
FB.api('/'+userid+'/albums/', 'get', function(response){
    if (!response || response.error) {
        albums = response.error;
    } else {
        albums = response;
    }
}); 
</script>
```

From there you can take your albums variable, which is going to give you an array of album ids.
Loop through each album, and use the same code FB.api to get '/'+userid+'/'+albumid+'/photos'

You can use the Graph API explorer to view all of the information you get back from each array
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET

Here's an example of the data returned from my profile pictures album:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=159665340734292%2Fphotos%2F

Hopefully that helps! If you need further explanation just let me know :)

Comment: Alright, thanks I am going to try it out. I can actually do it in JavaScript as well since it is a web application. The part that confused me is that all examples showed that I need a token in order to access this info.

Comment: Facebook is the most confusing platform to work on ever. Most of their documentation is vague or even wrong. Haha. You get an access token when you initialize the API, you don't have to specify it in the code. You don't have the prompt the user for any information as you're not accessing their information, only someone elses. But that's why the photos have to be public.

Comment: You're client won't need to grant the app access if the data is public. Otherwise she will need to grant access to photos, and access data anytime permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Wordpress based site then you have to follow below steps for making it possible:

1. As we know that Facebook Photo Fetcher plugin is available for Wordpress, first of all Install and make it active.
2. Now you have to make some setting for your Facebook Photo Fetcher in Setting >> FB Photo Fetcher.
3. After making the setting successfully, your plugin is successfully connected with your ID Facebook account.
4. Now you can insert your Facebook Album into Post or Page in Wordpress by searching for albums and getting the ID.
5. Create a new page or post in Wordpress with Html editor and insert below code:  , Change 234567890123456789 with your real Facebook album ID what you want.
6. Now save and check your page. Hope you will get your album in your Wordpress site.